# Проверка соответствия имени файла определённому формату

Tags: php

Мне нужно чтобы имя загружаемого файла было в формате XX-XX-XXXX, где каждый X - это цифра. Как сделать такую проверку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, для вашей задачи лучше использовать регулярное выражение \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно!

Comment: Только нужно еще добавить проверку на начало/конец строки

Comment: Так как мне нужна была дата, то в итоге получилось вот что: ^[0-3][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[2][0][2][0-9]$